# How to manipulate complex strings in php?

Tags: php, string

I am trying to group bunch of texts from a string and create an array for it.

The string is something like this:

```
<em>string</em>  and the <em>test</em> here.  
tableBegin rowNumber:2, columnNumber:2  11 22 33 44 tableEnd  
<em>end</em> text here
```

I was hoping to get an array like the following results

```
array (0 => '<em>string</em>  and the <em>test</em> here.',
         1=>'rowNumber:5',
         2=>'columnNumber:3',
         3=>'11',
         4=>'22',
         5=>'33',
         6=>'44'
         7=>'<em>end</em> text here')
```

`11,22,33,44` are the `table` cell data the user enters. I want to make them have unique `index` but keep the rest of texts together.

`tableBegin` and `tableEnd` are just the check for the `table cell` data

Any help or tips? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is not that clear. There are some texts left from your first block of text, not injected into your array list

Comment: You can use Regex to solve this. Too late to come up with a functional one though.

Comment: @Simon_eQ tableBeing and tableEnd are just the check for the string. I thought it would be helpful to add them. I don't want them into array.

Comment: I could make that using arrays/loops but it would be ugly.

Comment: @Simon_eQ anything helps..I am stuck..I will check it later though. it's very late here

Comment: Will the texts be longer/shorted or exactly the same length as shown in your first text

Comment: regex is definitely the way... not sure what data you are expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following, note that you need PHP 5.3+:

```
$string = '<em>string</em>  and the <em>test</em> here.  
tableBegin rowNumber:2, columnNumber:2  11 22 33 44 tableEnd
SOme other text
tableBegin rowNumber:3, columnNumber:3  11 22 33 44 55 tableEnd
<em>end</em> text here';

$array = array();
preg_replace_callback('#tableBegin\s*(.*?)\s*tableEnd\s*|.*?(?=tableBegin|$)#s', function($m)use(&$array){
    if(isset($m[1])){ // If group 1 exists, which means if the table is matched
        $array = array_merge($array, preg_split('#[\s,]+#s', $m[1])); // add the splitted string to the array
      // split by one or more whitespace or comma --^
    }else{// Else just add everything that's matched
        if(!empty($m[0])){
            $array[] = $m[0];
        }
    }
}, $string);
print_r($array);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => string  and the test here.  

    [1] => rowNumber:2
    [2] => columnNumber:2
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 22
    [5] => 33
    [6] => 44
    [7] => SOme other text

    [8] => rowNumber:3
    [9] => columnNumber:3
    [10] => 11
    [11] => 22
    [12] => 33
    [13] => 44
    [14] => 55
    [15] => end text here
)
```

**Regex explanation**

- `tableBegin` : match tableBegin
- `\s*` : match a whitespace zero or more times
- `(.*?)` : match everything ungreedy and put it in group 1
- `\s*` : match a whitespace zero or more times
- `tableEnd` : match tableEnd
- `\s*` : match a whitespace zero or more times
- `|` : or
- `.*?(?=tableBegin|$)` : match everything until `tableBegin` or end of line
- The `s` modifier : make dots also match newlines

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ugly way to do it, if you can't find a Regex guru out ther.

*So, this is your text*

```
$string =   "<em>string</em>  and the <em>test</em> here.  
tableBegin rowNumber:2, columnNumber:2  11 22 33 44 tableEnd  
<em>end</em> text here";
```

*And this is my code*

```
$E = explode(' ', $string);
$A =  $E[0].$E[1].$E[2].$E[3].$E[4].$E[5];
$B =  $E[17].$E[18].$E[19];
$All = [$A, $E[8],$E[9], $E[11], $E[12], $E[13], $E[14], $B];

print_r($All);
```

*And this is the output*

```
Array
(
    [0] => stringandthetesthere.
    [1] => rowNumber:2,
    [2] => columnNumber:2
    [3] => 11
    [4] => 22
    [5] => 33
    [6] => 44
    [7] => endtexthere
)
```

off-course, the `<em>` tags won't be visible, unless view the source code.

Comment: RegEx is the better answer, but I took your aproach as well with using `explode`s. Here's my version: http://codepad.org/iSWnWSPm